# How to catch exception when calling a "syscall/js" function?

Tags: javascript, go, exception, system-calls, webassembly

I’m experiencing the use of the `syscall/js` GO package and I would like to find a way to catch exception on a call to a `js` function.

Here an example of a call throwing an exception to the browser: (You need to disable the access to the localstorage to raise the exception.)

```golang
value := js.Global().Get("window").Get("localStorage")
...
```

As soon as this code execute an exception is raised by the browser:
[image]

and the go/wasm code stops.

How to catch this exception to be able to resume the code and to handle the error with the UI?

regards

No clue what to try!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do something like:

```
var localStorage;
    
try {
  localStorage = window.localStorage;
} catch(e) {
  // Access denied :-(
}

value := localStorage;
```

Comment: I've updated the post to clarify that I'm using the syscall/js package in GO. And in go you can not try/catch exceptions.